# How to display the page numbers of included pdf files like "pp: x-x" in headers?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, pdfpages

I want to include about 500-600 conference papers in a root file. My root file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancyhead[L]{pp: ?-?}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The codes that produces `pdf-1.pdf` and `pdf-2.pdf` are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{The first Paper}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{The Second Paper}
\author{Joe Smith}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[6-18]
\end{document}
```

Now I want to display the page numbers of included pdf files as "page range" like `pp: x-x` in headers. For example, for all pages of the first included pdf file which is 4 pages long, I want to have `pp: 1-4` on all headers of its 4 pages, like the screenshot below and for the second paper, I wanna have `pp: 5-7`.

[image]

**How can I do that?**
Please also note that I'm using xelatex and some of my included pdf files are not in the current directory (I set their path in the `\includepdf` command).

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly want. Is the difference between `pp: xx-xx` and `pp: ??--??` only single and double dash (`-`) or you mean something particular by `xx` and `??`?

Comment: @Pouya: Suppose my first paper is 4 pages long and the second one is 3 pages long. I want to show their page numbers like "pp: 1-4" on the first 4 pages and "pp: 5-7" on the second 3 pages in headers. Am I clear enough now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REVISED SOLUTION (2-pass compile, with a little manual intervention)

If I spent more time, I could probably remove the manual intervention.  But the OP would like to accomplish the task without knowing the length (in advance) of the included sub-documents.  For this, I employ the "survey" feature of the `pdfpages` package.

I have the code, in which two lines must be uncommented/modified for the 2nd pass.  These are the lines to pay particular attention to:

```
%%%%%
% AFTER 1ST RUN, ADD THIS LAST ONE MANUALLY
%\newlabel{pdfpages@page?}{{}{?}}% CREATE THIS BASED ON aux FILE
%\revisegetthepages% UNCOMMENT THIS FOR 2ND PASS
%%%%%
```

For the first pass, here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[enable-survey]{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\newlabel[2]{\getfirstpage#2%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\thefirstpage}}
\newcommand\getfirstpage[2]{\gdef\thefirstpage{#2}}
\newcommand\getthepages{\edef\startpage{?}\edef\endpage{?}}
\def\revisegetthepages{\def\getthepages{%
  \edef\startpage{\csname pdfpages@page\arabic{localdoc}\endcsname}%
  \stepcounter{localdoc}%
  \edef\tmp{\csname pdfpages@page\arabic{localdoc}\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{tmpcount}{\tmp}%
  \addtocounter{tmpcount}{-1}%
  \def\endpage{\thetmpcount}%
}}
%%%%%
% AFTER 1ST RUN, ADD THIS LAST ONE MANUALLY
%\newlabel{pdfpages@page?}{{}{?}}% CREATE THIS BASED ON aux FILE
%\revisegetthepages% UNCOMMENT THIS FOR 2ND PASS
%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancyhead[L]{pp: ?-?}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\newcounter{tmpcount}
\newcounter{localdoc}
\newcommand\Includepdf[1]{%
  \getthepages%
  \global\fancyhead[L]{pp: \startpage--\endpage}
\AddToSurvey
  \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\Includepdf{pdf-1.pdf}
\Includepdf{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

It creates a document with placeholders, such as this:

[image]

More importantly, the `\AddToSurvey` features places these lines in the `aux` file:

```
\relax
\newlabel{pdfpages@page0}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{pdfpages@page1}{{}{5}}
```

Edit the similar line in the preamble to reflect what it would be for the next included document, if there were one.  Also, uncomment the `\revisegetthepages` line in the preamble.  These are the key additions/modifications from the first pass

```
%%%%%
% AFTER 1ST RUN, ADD THIS LAST ONE MANUALLY
\newlabel{pdfpages@page2}{{}{8}}% CREATE THIS BASED ON aux FILE
\revisegetthepages% UNCOMMENT THIS FOR 2ND PASS
%%%%%
```

Here is the 2nd-pass version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[enable-survey]{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\newlabel[2]{\getfirstpage#2%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\thefirstpage}}
\newcommand\getfirstpage[2]{\gdef\thefirstpage{#2}}
\newcommand\getthepages{\edef\startpage{?}\edef\endpage{?}}
\def\revisegetthepages{\def\getthepages{%
  \edef\startpage{\csname pdfpages@page\arabic{localdoc}\endcsname}%
  \stepcounter{localdoc}%
  \edef\tmp{\csname pdfpages@page\arabic{localdoc}\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{tmpcount}{\tmp}%
  \addtocounter{tmpcount}{-1}%
  \def\endpage{\thetmpcount}%
}}
%%%%%
% AFTER 1ST RUN, ADD THIS LAST ONE MANUALLY
\newlabel{pdfpages@page2}{{}{8}}% CREATE THIS BASED ON aux FILE
\revisegetthepages% UNCOMMENT THIS FOR 2ND PASS
%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancyhead[L]{pp: ?-?}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\newcounter{tmpcount}
\newcounter{localdoc}
\newcommand\Includepdf[1]{%
  \getthepages%
  \global\fancyhead[L]{pp: \startpage--\endpage}
\AddToSurvey
  \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\Includepdf{pdf-1.pdf}
\Includepdf{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

It produces the desired document with subdocument page delimiters specified in the header.

[image]

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (provide sub-document length manually)

Here I create `\Includepdf{pages}{filename}`, which uses argument `#1` to update a counter, and to change the `\fancyhead[L]{}` on the fly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancyhead[L]{pp: ?-?}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\newcounter{localpage}
\newcommand\Includepdf[2]{%
  \global\fancyhead[L]{pp: \the\numexpr\thelocalpage+1\relax%
    --\the\numexpr\thelocalpage+#1\relax}
  \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{#2}%
  \addtocounter{localpage}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\Includepdf{4}{pdf-1.pdf}
\Includepdf{3}{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but due to the high number of my papers, isn't there a way to automatically do this?

Comment: @Sisabe Let me have a look at the `pdfpages` documentation to see if the # of pages extracted is available in some way.

Comment: @Sisabe I don't see anything there.  What it would probably take is two compiler passes.  On the first, information about the page count would be written out to the `aux` file, and on the second pass, it would be read back in and used to set the headers.  That would be much more complicated to do... don't know if I can get to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. I'll await for further answers. +1'd your answer.

Comment: @Sisabe I've continued to revise to speed the process.

Comment: So in the `\newlabel{pdfpages@pageX}{{}{Y}}` command, the `X` is the number of the included files and the `Y` is the total pages of the root file +1. right?

Comment: @Sisabe Yes, with the proviso that you don't add extra content after the last included file.  In that case, it is the page number of the first page of included content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21680/discussion-between-sisabe-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancyhead[L]{pp: \themtp-\mtt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mtp}
\let\mtpdf\includepdf
\def\includepdf[#1]#2{%
\def\mtt{\pageref{#2}}%
\mtpdf[#1]{#2}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{#2}{{}{\themtp}{}{}}}%
\setcounter{mtp}{0}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{mtp}\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{mtp}\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

we don't realy need `\refstepcounter` we can replace it by `\stepcounter`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work with `hyperref` package. Could you please modify your code to work with this package?

Comment: @Sisabe what do you want with hyperref?

Comment: I want it to hyperlink my Table of Contents headings, formulas, citations and so on.

Comment: @Sisabe maybe you should ask another question with MWE of what you need. I can't see here any table of contents. your pdf files are included as images so any link therein is destroyed

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. The problem is: If I load the `hyperref` package in your code, I'll get several errors. You can check this  yourself. So how can solve this problem?

Comment: @Sisabe i edit my answer we need \string\newlabel{#2}{{}{\themtp}{}{}}